# Como dar um tab em um echo do PHP?

Tags: php, html

Tenho o seguinte código que gera um os códigos de um `insert` automático pra mim. Meu sistema é uma espécie de gerador de `querys` já prontas, apenas passo os parâmetros. Passo os parametros em uma pagina e dou o submit pra enviar os valores pra outra pagina, que executa a função e mostra os códigos já prontos.

```
if($gM)
{
    if($gI)
    {
        foreach ($varUpper as $key) 
        {
            if(!isset($string))
            {
                $string = "'\".\$this->get$key().\"', <br>";
            }
            else
            {
               $string .= "'\".\$this->get$key().\"', <br>"; 
            }

            $resultado = substr($string, 0, -6);
        }

        echo 'protected function insert()<br>{<br>$query = "<br>INSERT INTO '.$tabela.'<br> (<br>'.implode(',<br> ', $colunas).'<br>) <br>VALUES <br>(<br>'.$resultado.'<br>)";';

        echo '<br><br>';

        echo 'return Dao::getInstancia()->execute($query);<br>}';
    }
}
```

Tenho esse retorno (Supondo que a tabela chama "usuario" e as colunas são "nome_usuario", "user_usuario" e "senha_usuario"):

```
protected function insert()
{
$query = "
INSERT INTO usuario
(
nome_usuario,
user_usuario,
senha_usuario
)
VALUES
(
'".$this->getNome_Usuario()."',
'".$this->getUser_Usuario()."',
'".$this->getSenha_Usuario()."'
)";

return Dao::getInstancia()->execute($query);
}
```

Porém, eu gostaria que o retorno fosse assim:

```
protected function insert()
{
    $query = "
        INSERT INTO usuario
        (
            nome_usuario,
            user_usuario,
            senha_usuario
        )
        VALUES
        (
            '".$this->getNome_Usuario()."',
            '".$this->getUser_Usuario()."',
            '".$this->getSenha_Usuario()."'
        )";

    return Dao::getInstancia()->execute($query);
}
```

Reparem nos `tabs` que foram adicionados, como eu poderia fazer isso? Já tentei usar `\t` e mostrar com `n2lbr` porém não funcionou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se vai exibir essa consulta no navegador coloque ela entre a tag `<pre>` e use o `\t` para indicar um tab na string. Pode indicar se deseja essa formatação com um parâmetro adiciona na chamado do méotodo.

```
protected function insert($debug=false)
{

    $debug = $debug ? array('<pre>', '</pre>') : array('','');

    $query = sprintf("%s
        INSERT INTO usuario
        (
            nome_usuario,
            user_usuario,
            senha_usuario
        )
        VALUES
        (
            '".$this->getNome_Usuario()."',
            '".$this->getUser_Usuario()."',
            '".$this->getSenha_Usuario()."'
        )%s",  ...$debug);

    return Dao::getInstancia()->execute($query);
}
```

Exemplo simplificado:

```
$t = true;
$tag = $t ? array('<pre>', '</pre>') : array('', '');
printf('%s >>texto<< %s', ...$tag);
```